# $\int _{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}{1+x^2}$ convergent?

Tags: real-analysis

Is the integral $\int _{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}{1+x^2}$ convergent?

I got the integrals $\int _{-1}^{\infty}f(x)dt$ and $\int _{1}^{\infty}f(x)dt$ convergent by $\mu$ test but the answer is divergent .Where am I wrong?

Comment: You are wrong because the given integral is divergent when $x$ goes to minus infinity. The integral becomes convergent if the lower limit is some finite number (could be negative) and the upper limit infinity. That can then be easily verified by comparison test

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{e^x}{x} = \infty,$$

and there is $K> 1$ such that for $x \geqslant K$

$$\frac{e^x}{x^2}> \frac1{x}.$$

Then

$$\int_{-R}^{-1}\frac{e^{-x}}{1+x^2}\,dx = \int_{1}^{R}\frac{e^{x}}{1+x^2}\,dx \\> \int_{1}^{R}\frac{e^{x}}{2x^2}\,dx> \int_{K}^{R}\frac{1}{2x}\,dx=\frac1{2}[\ln R - \ln K]$$

and

$$\lim_{R \to \infty}\int_{-R}^{-1}\frac{e^{-x}}{1+x^2}\,dx = \infty$$.